# Laravel 4 route wildcard need to all routes

Tags: regex, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a wildcard route that will accept anything after `/live`. What I've got at the moment matches anything but not if there are multiple folders (slashes), so this matches:

```
/live/debate
```

But these don't:

```
/live
/live/debate/1
```

How can I get the route to match *all* possible routes starting with 'live'?

Current code:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'live', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::any('{all}', [ 'as' => 'live.index', 'uses' => 'LiveController@index' ])->where('all', '[^/]*');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are explicitely excluding slashes with `[^/]` in your regex.

Change it to this:

```
->where('all', '.*');
```